# How to trim every element of a field which is an array of strings in a Mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose, in a Mongoose schema, there is a field like:

```
  description:{
        type:[String],
        required:[true,"Product description is required"],
        validate: {
            validator: array => {
              return array.length > 0 && array.every(str => str.trim() !== '');
            },
            message: "At least one description point is required.",
        },
        trim:true,  // this trim is misplaced
    }
```

Is the trim misplaced? I want it to trim every element of the array 'description' which is an array of strings. In other words, I want each of the strings to be trimmed and not the containing array itself. But the current code seems to trim on the array itself. What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps this can be achieved by using [sub-schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schemas).

Comment: You should use the pre middleware to transform the array.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose trim works for string type so you need to update the schema to have an object descriping the string not the array

```js
description: {
  type: [{ type: String, trim: true }],
  required:[true,"Product description is required"],
  validate: {
     validator: array => {
       return array.length > 0 && array.every(str => str.trim() !== '');
     },
     message: "At least one description point is required.",
  },
},
```